# Implementing "true" Single Sign-On: OpenID, something else, or custom hack?

Tags: authentication, web-applications, single-sign-on

We're trying to evaluate a solution to implement "true" SSO for multiple (already existing) web solutions. True SSO here means to login on any service, and be authenticated on all, without further actions from the user.

All of the applications we're going to use support OpenID and/or have plugins that allow OpenID, so this seems like something worth looking into. However, as I understand OpenID, the users would still be required to enter their OpenID credentials in each service.

Is there a sane way to implement SSO with automatic login once the OpenID provider has authenticated the user?

In an earlier project, we hacked up the PHP session data in the login procedures of two applications (both running on the same domain and server) so a login in the first application creates the session data for the other application as well. However, this is a very hacky solution and is prone to break when either application is updated, so we're trying to avoid it this time.

Are there any other SSO solutions that we could look into?

Comment: This one is more for http://security.stackechange.com ;)

Answer (score 0):

i am assuming that you have the control on the SSO implementation

there are some things you can do to make sure that once the user has been recognized by the SSO application, he will virtually automatically be logged in to your other applications

1. in your SSO application, create a whitelist of service providers. authentication request from those websites will be automatically approved. thus, user won't be asked to approve the request manually
2. in your application, set the return_to parameter as the page the user is intending to immediately open. don't simply set the return_to to that application homepage

by the way, the most standard openid implementation accepts any url. however, if you want to use the sso in a controlled environment, you can set the service provider to have a whitelist of trusted identity providers. after all, it's the service provider which initiated openid authentication.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a means to do this. Run an Application Server, Node Based, and register cross-domain techniques to offer cookie-credentialed (backed up by site-handshakes as each new user arrives, to scale better and minimize resource expenditure per-session).

I am working on such a beast right now, and I'm 5/6th done.

I have taken care of several annoying variables up front- including the means to assure unique user logon- and I've taken a stand on other issues- one just can't get everything done in one system. However, one can have a true SSO if one is willing to pull out some stops. It is YOUR stops which will define your solution. If you have not accurately portrayed your limitations then there isn't a solution which can be offered for implementation here, and the nature of your problem is ENTIRELY implementation- not theory. In theory you have 4-5 different options. In practice you will find your answers.